# Visualizing a multivariate normal distribution in 3D with python

Tags: python, visualization, normal-distribution

Does anyone know how to make a pretty visualization of the PDF of multivariate (bivariate for simply) normal distribution, with each variable's distribution is projected, like the below figure? Thanks in advance.

Source of the figure: 
[image: A 3D plot]
from [this thesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320182941_Bayesian_tracking_of_multiple_point_targets_using_Expectation_Maximization).

Answer (score 1):

This plot is almost certainly produced using [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/index.html). Take a look at their [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html). Stack Overflow also has a [`matplotlib` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib).

To plot in 3D you need to use the [`mplot3d`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def gauss1(x):
    return np.exp(-(x**2))

def gauss(x, y):
    return gauss1(x)*gauss1(2*y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = gauss(X, Y)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, alpha=0.4, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-4, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=4, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

This produces the following result

[image]

I am not sure how to plot only the contour lines for the projections, but this should get you started.